# Laravel how to get the url to be what is in the .env

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I currently got my env file looking like this:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

When I run the project using artisan command (php artisan serve), I get the following path:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

However the above link doesn't work instead I get a 404. To access my website, I am using the below link:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

I am not sure why its not using what is on the .env file which it should be (http://localhost)

Please can someone help me solve this issue. I have been trying to google about this but there's not much it says on the website.

I am using Laravel 5.8

Thanks

Comment: Try hosting another port php artisan serve 0.0.0.0:8004 .

Comment: @GorkhaliKhadka tried this but not working

Answer (score 1):

The `php artisan serve` is a simple command and does not read your configuration.

You can either ignore what it says and just open `http://localhost:8000` to start working or use `php artisan server --host=localhost` which should get you the same result.

See here for how it's implemented: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/46beec229568c4a09a61e2e3755b0afc06ae4795/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php#L114